# Grails not running because of class bootstrap not found

Tags: grails, groovy

I am using grails 2.5.6 and Java 7.

When i enter the command "grails run-app" i receive the following error message "Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap". I have tried resetting to a previous commit that i know was working, run "grails clean", "grails refresh dependencies", delete the target folder, check for files where i may have a different name on the file and the class name but none of that has worked so far. I am not able to find the error on the stacktrace (which i attach) so any other ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
2019-01-31 14:51:12,012 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:124)
    ... 25 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,017 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:124)
    ... 25 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,019 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:677)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:787)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:775)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.<init>(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsApplicationFactoryBean.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5099)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5615)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-01-31 14:51:12,021 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,022 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,022 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,022 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-01-31 14:51:12,022 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,116 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,118 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,118 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-01-31 14:51:12,118 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,119 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,119 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,119 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-01-31 14:51:12,119 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,120 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,120 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
2019-01-31 14:51:12,120 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-01-31 14:51:12,121 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: BootStrap
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BootStrap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i deleted BootStrap.groovy and it is running now. I hope it does not cause more issues in the future.

Comment: What did your BootStrap.groovy file look like? There might have been an error in the file... You can always create a new BootStrap file, here's s link to a clean BootStrap file: https://github.com/virtualdogbert/testEnforcer2/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy

Comment: @virtualdogbert i recreated the file following the example you gave and now it works. It does not have any package... at the beginning of the file. Is that correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: In Grails 2 I don't think the package was required, or used, however if and when you move to Grails 3 then you should moved it to a package, although it also changes to be under an init folder.